# Clarification of function pointers

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

```
int function_a () {
   int ret_a = call_a;
   int ret_b = call_b;
}
```

Definition of call_a and call_b is something like this:

```
int call_a() {
  // Some 10 lines
  call_c();
}

int call_b() {
  // Same 10 lines
  call_d();
}
```

Only difference between functions call_a and call_b is that they are calling different functions. I came to know that function pointers is the best approach in such situations. Make one function(only call_a, instead of both call_a and call_b) and pass function pointers to call_c and call_d in it. How can we achieve it?

Hope I am clear enough to make you understand.

Comment: You don't need function pointers. Just pass some kind of flag (bool, enum, etc.) to determine if `call_c` or `call_d` should be used.

Comment: Your code is invalid C++. What’s your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can we achieve it?

```
void call_c();
void call_d();

int call_a(void (*c)()) {
  // Some 10 lines
  c();
}

int function_a () {
   int ret_a = call_a(&call_c);
   int ret_b = call_a(&call_d);
}
```

---

> I came to know that function pointers is the best approach in such situations

Sometimes, it's not. It may be, depending on your true use case, that using lambdas makes more sense!

```
template <typename Callable>
int call_a(Callable c) {
  // Some 10 lines
  c();
}

int function_a () {
   int ret_a = call_a([]() { call_c(); });
   int ret_b = call_a([]() { call_d(); });
}
```

Comment: @Angew: No, it requires `call_a` to be implemented precisely once in every translation unit which requires it

Comment: Yes, true. Which, in practice, translates to being implemented in a header file (corrected comment from "header" to "header file").

Comment: @Angew: No, not necessarily. A header file conventionally is any file with the extension `.h`, but conventionally we write template function definitions in files with extension `.ipp` or similar, to distinguish them from headers.

Comment: Who's "we?" For me, anything which gets `#include`d rather than compiled directly is a header file. But OK, I will change it: this requires `call_a` to be implemented in an `#include`d file.

Comment: @Angew: Again, no, it does not. You appear to be ascribing more power to files name `*.h` and the `#include` mechanism than they deserve. "We" means the majority of C++ programmers, writing canonical C++ code.

Comment: 1. For the record, I am not the downvoter - I actually upvoted your answer. 2. All I mean is `#include` is probably the most common (and certainly the easiest) way to get the definition into all translation units which need it. And that bears the cost of public availability, recompilation requirements etc. I assume even your `.ipp` files are `#include`d somewhere. And I'd say using `.ipp` or similar files is project-specific coding style more than "canonical C++ code."

Comment: @Angew: Okay, so it appears you have the technical facts down in your head. I just wanted to point out that your assertion "this requires call_a to be implemented in an #included file" is entirely incorrect. It's only a convention.

Answer (score 2):

Are you perhaps looking for this?

```
typedef void Subroutine();  //The signature of the function you want to call through pointer

int call_generic(Subroutine *subroutine)
{
  //10 lines
  soubroutine();
}
```

It would be called like this:

```
int main()
{
  call_generic(&call_c);
  //or
  call_generic(&call_d);
}
```